# Divisibility by 24 of Fourier coefficients of eta function expressions

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms

I have a collection of series $f(p) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n p^n$ with integer coefficients constructed out of the Dedekind eta function $\eta$, and this collection (experimentally) exhibits the property that $24 | n c_n$.  For instance,
$$
\begin{split}
f(p) &= \frac{p}{2\eta(p)^{24}} + \frac{3p\eta(p^2)^{48}}{2\eta(p)^{24}\eta(p^4)^{24}}\\
&= 2 + 48 p + 576 p^2 + 4672 p^3 + 29628 p^4 + 161856 p^5 + \dots
\end{split}$$ (in this particular case, $48 | n c_n$).  I am wondering how one would prove such statements.

Edit: The statement is equivalent to 24 dividing $df/dp$. Taking a derivative and using the differential identities for eta functions, one can show divisibility by 12. But I fail to show divisibility by 24 or 48.

Comment: In your example, since all the $\eta$'s appearing are 24th powers, I would be tempted to try rewriting it as a congruence between integer-weight modular forms (or maybe quasimodular forms).